# Setting default <select> value with asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop-down list

```
<select ng-model="referral.organization"
    ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in organizations">
</select>
```

where `organizations` is filled using a $http request. I also have a resource `referral` which includes several properties, including an integer `organization` that corresponds to the value saved in the drop-down. Currently, the drop-down works fine and selecting a new value will update my `referral` resource without issue.

However, when the page loads the drop-down is blank rather than displaying the value of `referral.organization` that was retrieved from the server (that is, when opening a previously saved `referral` form). I understand that this is likely due to my resource being empty when the page first loads, but how do I update the drop-down when the information has been successfully retrieved?

Edit:
`{{ organizations[referral.organization] }}` successfully lists the selected value if placed somewhere else on the page, but I do not know how to give the  tag this expression to display.

Second Edit:
The problem was apparently a mismatch between the key used in ngOptions and the variable used in ngModel. The `<select>` option's were being returned as strings from WebAPI (despite beginning as Dictionary) while the `referral` model was returning integers. When `referral.organization` was placed in ngModel, Angular was not matching 2723 to "2723" and so forth.

I tried several different things, but the following works well and is the "cleanest" to me. In the callback for the $resource GET, I simply change the necessary variables to strings like so:

```
$scope.referral = $resource("some/resource").get(function (data) {
                data.organization = String(data.organization);
                ...
            });
```

Not sure if this would be considered a problem with Angular (not matching 1000 to "1000") or WebAPI (serializing `Dictionary<int,String>` to `{ "key":"value" }`) but this is functional and the `<select>` tag is still bound to the `referral` resource.

Comment: Is this question (and these answers) more about the fact that the options are asynchronous or more about the fact that the options are objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers were correct in that it usually "just works." The issue was ultimately a mismatch between the `organization` key (an integer) stored inside `$scope.organizations` and the key as stored in the `$http` response, which is stored in JSON and therefore as a string. Angular was not matching the string to the integer. As I mentioned in my edit to the original question, the solution at the time was to cast the `$http` response data to a string. I am not sure if current versions of Angular.js still behave this way.

Answer (score 3):

For simple types you can just set `$scope.referral.organization` and it'll magically work:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBJK9/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="referral.organization" ng-options="c for c in organizations">
    </select>
</div>
```

-

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.organizations = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    $scope.referral = {
        organization: 'c'
    };
}
```

If you're using objects, it gets trickier since Angular doesn't seem smart enough to know the new object is virtually the same.  Unless there's some Angular hack, the only way I see forward is to update `$scope.referral.organization` after it gets loaded from the server and assign it to a value from `$scope.organizations` like:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBJK9/2/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="referral.organization" ng-options="c.name for c in organizations"></select>
    {{referral}}
    <button ng-click="loadReferral()">load referral</button>
</div>
```

-

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.organizations = [{name:'a'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'c'}, {name:'d'}, {name:'e'}];
    $scope.referral = {
        organization: $scope.organizations[2]
    };
    $scope.loadReferral = function () {
        $scope.referral = {
            other: 'parts',
            of: 'referral',
            organization: {name:'b'}
        };

        // look up the correct value
        angular.forEach($scope.organizations, function(value, key) {
            if ($scope.organizations[key].name === value.name) {
                $scope.referral.organization = $scope.organizations[key];
                return false;
            }
        });

    };
}
```

Comment: `referral` is retrieved using a GET request to my WebApi (e.g. `api/referrals/{id}`). Existing referral forms have the `organization` variable already, and in fact `organizations[referral.organization]` works. However, I do not know how to display this value in the <select> element, it only works if I do something like `{{ organizations[referral.organization] }}` elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Exactly. I always forget I can create my own jsfiddle or something to accompany a question.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/qBJK9/2/, since you need a reference to an object that exists in memory.  Otherwise you can structure your `select` so that it just uses simple values and can easily be updated from a value from the server.  Unless there's some Angular hack that does it for you?  I'm not seeing anything though.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `referral.organization` to one of objects obtained from ajax:

```
$scope.referral.organization = $scope.organizations[0]
```

I created simple demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssFPj9?p=preview). Button click handler changes list of objects and selects default one.

```
$scope.changeModel = function() {
  $scope.listOfObjects = [{id: 4, name: "miss1"},
                          {id: 5, name: "miss2"},
                          {id: 6, name: "miss3"}];
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.listOfObjects[1];
};
```