# how to set the default 'select' ng-model to an object?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do a search engine interface with angular. The user selects some parameters in a form, click "search" and then it fills the url with the parameters using `$location.search()`

the search interface parameters which are used to build the form :

```
params = {
    milestones: [ "a", "b", "c", "d", etc. ], 
    properties: [ 
        { "name": "name A", type: "text" }, 
        { "name": "name B", type: "checkbox" }, 
        { etc. }
    ]
}
```

inside the controller :

```
$scope.query = $location.search();  // get the parameters from the url  
$scope.search = function (query) {  // set the parameters to the url
    $location.search(query);    
};
```

and the html of the form

```
<select ng-model="query.milestone_name" ng-options="ms for ms in params.milestones">
    <option value="">-select milestone-</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="property" ng-options="prop.name for prop in params.properties" ng-change="query.property_name=property.name">
<!-- if the object 'property' was passed in the url, it would look like this `%5Bobject%20Object%5D`, so its 'name' parameter is converted to a string -->
    <option value="">-select property-</option>
</select>
<span ng-switch="property.type">
    <label ng-switch-when="text">{{query.property_name}}: <input type="text" ng-model="query.property_value"></label>
    <label ng-switch-when="checkbox">{{query.property_name}}: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="query.property_value"></label>
</span>
<button ng-click="search(query)">search</button>
```

and somewhere else in the page is the list of results.

the user can also access to a search result page with an url like this:

```
http://myapp.com/search?milestone_name=a&property_name=name%20A
```

almost everything works fine : the list of results is displayed, the "milestone" parameter is pre-selected with the correct value in the `select` component, but not the "property" parameter because it's not a string, it's an object.

how can i set the default value (ng-model) of the select component to an object ?

or any other idea on how i should do this ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When using an array of objects for the select to iterate over, the `ng-options` directive needs to have an attribute of the object to match against (and differentiate between arrays)

Use the `track by` section of the directive declaration eg

```
<select ng-model="property" ng-options="prop.name for prop in params.properties track by prop.name" ng-change="query.property_name=property.name">
<!-- if the object 'property' was passed in the url, it would look like this `%5Bobject%20Object%5D`, so its 'name' parameter is converted to a string -->
    <option value="">-select property-</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is so exactly what I needed to do.

                    <select ng-options="team as team.name for team in options.teams track by team.name" ng-model="account.details.team" class="form-control"></select>

Comment: worked for me too. `track by` did the job. If you want to filter the list it must be used at the end of the expression as this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21416725/2071612) suggests

Comment: i've tried "track by" but the option values still look like this "object:875" and my ng-selected is not working

Answer (score 3):

You can use this form of comprehension expression in ngOptions: [label **group by** group **for** value **in** array](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Html drop down list will display only name of selected object. Model will contain whole selected object. You can set selected object from controller.

```
  <select ng-model="property"
          ng-options="prop as prop.name for prop in params.properties">
  </select>
```

Check this [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sPKcfW3ZTEBy2jaWkvDM?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options` is generating some options to be used with `ng-model`.  In your syntax (`prop.name for prop in params.properties`) you've told it to bind to the object found in the array (as oppose to a property on it - which is what you want to do) and use its name property as the value to display.  So when you try and set the `ng-model` to be an object that's not in the `ng-options` array nothing happens - I'm guessing because it's using reference/shallow equality and not deep equality.  So what you should do is either:

- Convert the `ng-options` object to be an array of strings.
- Use a syntax that involves keys, such as:

`prop.name as prop.name for prop in params.properties`

http://jsfiddle.net/C5ENK/

If that doesn't suit your needs let me know why and I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem is that i need the full object to be bind to `ng-model`, for exemple to retrieve its "type" property used in the following `ng-switch`. with your solutions i think it's not possible?

Comment: If that's your only problem you make your properties a lookup instead of an array you could do You could just do `<span ng-switch="properties[property.name].type">`.  Let me know if that doesn't make sense or, if it does, if that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i found a kind of solution…

when selecting a property, it saves the index of this object and then when the page loads, it sets the ng-model of the `select` to the value of this index. it uses this : [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16093334/2112538) for setting the index and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668283/2112538) for getting the value of this index in the array of objects.