# Filtering an Angular 1.2 ng-repeat with "track by" by a boolean property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to filter some list items based on the value of a boolean property, but no matter what I do the entire list is always displayed. A few of the the things I've tried have been so broken that nothing displays, but that's neither here nor there. I can't get my filtering working as desired:

```
$scope.attendees = [
     {"firstname":"Steve",    "lastname":"Jobs",  "arrived":true,  "id":1}
    ,{"firstname":"Michelle", "lastname":"Jobs",  "arrived":false, "id":2}
    ,{"firstname":"Adam",     "lastname":"Smith", "arrived":true,  "id":3}
    ,{"firstname":"Megan",    "lastname":"Smith", "arrived":false, "id":4}
    ,{"firstname":"Dylan",    "lastname":"Smith", "arrived":false, "id":5}
    ,{"firstname":"Ethan",    "lastname":"Smith", "arrived":false, "id":6}
];
```

Using the following ng-repeat filtering:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in attendees track by person.id | filter:arrived:'false'">
            {{person.lastname}}, {{person.firstname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I feel like I've tried every permutation that I can find referenced, most of which came from various StackOverflow search results:

- `filter:'arrived'`
- `filter:arrived`
- `filter:'person.arrived'`
- `filter:person.arrived`
- `filter:{arrived:true}`
- `filter:{arrived:'true'}`
- `filter:{person.arrived:true}`
- `filter:{person.arrived:'true'}`

I've also tried creating a custom filter function:

```
$scope.isArrived = function(item) {
    return item.arrived;
};
```

And applying it thusly:

- `filter:isArrived`
- `filter:'isArrived'`
- `filter:{isArrived(person)}`
- `filter:isArrived(person)`
- `filter:'isArrived(person)'`

None of these seems to work. What am I missing?

[Here's a plnkr that demonstrates my problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/gitKALVXwFoQEe2RR7R6?p=preview).

Answer (score 256, accepted):

The track by needs to be at the end of the expression:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in attendees | filter: {arrived: false } track by person.id">
```

Comment: How flipping annoying, and a waste of 30 minutes. I wish it used `trackBy: ..` and acted normally "like everything else".

Comment: This is a very important point. Tracking by unique values that were largely identical for most of the leading characters, we were getting a duplicates error because track by wasn't last in the expression. Pretty obscure error imo.

Answer (score 4):

[*@Gruff's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21416725/4927984) is right, but just to give an answer from an official source:

> From the Angular [`ng-repeat` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):
>
> Note: **`track by` must always be the last expression**:
>
> ```
> <div ng-repeat="model in collection | orderBy: 'id' as filtered_result track by model.id">
>   {{model.name}}
> </div>
> ```

It also appear on the "Arguments" part of the docs:

> Note that the tracking expression must come last, after any filters,
> and the alias expression.