# AngularJS: Using 'track by' disables filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Since I implemented [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) into `ng-repeat`, it prevents my filter from executing. For example, `track by $index` works like a charm but when I try to add an input field to search my object, nothing happens and the console does not show any error.

Here is my html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<div ng-repeat="message in messages.collection track by $index | filter : searchText">
  <p>{{message.text}}</p>
</div>
```

I also created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gTfQyW0H7TNCHemkhTew) in order to show both cases (with and without `track by`).

I would like to know if it is a syntax problem or something else in order to fix it.

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416198/filtering-an-angular-1-2-ng-repeat-with-track-by-by-a-boolean-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `track by` at the end of the expression. See this working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLQ6lWgysRRYgJNQewdT?p=preview).

**Code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages.collection | filter : searchText track by $index">
    <p>{{message.text}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please rather try to track by on the filter

```
message in messages.collection  | filter : searchText track by $index
```

As suggested on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Best