# ngRepeat: filter not working when using track by $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my html

```
<body>
<div ng-app="repeatdemo" ng-controller="rd">
<input type="text" ng-model="nameSearch" />
<div ng-repeat="x in names track by $index | filter : nameSearch">
{{x }}
</div>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
<script>
var rdapp=angular.module("repeatdemo",[]);
rdapp.controller("rd",function($scope){
$scope.names=['deepu','vicky','hello','hey','vickys'];

});
</script>
```

When i am using track by `$index in repeat` option , the filter is not working
Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3xnzvvs/) and try removing `track by index` in `ng-repeat`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Using 'track by' disables filter in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647126/angularjs-using-track-by-disables-filter-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416198/filtering-an-angular-1-2-ng-repeat-with-track-by-by-a-boolean-property <-- found a match in that match

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem is the order you're applying the filter and the track by in

http://jsfiddle.net/n3xnzvvs/1/

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names | filter : nameSearch track by $index">
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and it solved. I was getting the error Error: filter:notarray Not an array, when doing the way vignash was. Can you explain why that causes the error?

Answer (score 6):

If you check the documentation for [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) you'll find this in the description of the ngRepeat parameter:

> For example: item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id is a pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction with a tracking expression.

Your code for the ng-repeat directive should look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names | filter: nameSearch track by $index">
```

Comment: ah beat me to the trigger :)

Comment: @shaunhusain yep, also I think a quote straight from docs is equal to your link to a code example hah