# Angular 1.5 filter with ng-repeat not working by track by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material, javascript-objects

so I tried so many different ways to get this done. Followed so many StackOverflow and could not get this to work. All I am trying to do is to filter some list items based on the value of a boolean property. Below is the picture of my object data. The closest example I am following is this question [Filtering an Angular 1.2 ng-repeat with "track by" by a boolean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416198/filtering-an-angular-1-2-ng-repeat-with-track-by-by-a-boolean-property). Still not working. does it have anything to do with an object literal and this type of filtering with property only works with array? I am new to javascript so not sure. Also using angular material, virtual repeat container and other material based things are not affecting the result, I can display the whole data, just the filtered by this specific property not working
[image]

```js
      loadAssets = () => {

        var self = this;
        self.infiniteAssets = {
            numLoaded_: 0,
            toLoad_: 0,
            items: [],
            pageNum:1,
            virtualIndex:0,

            getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
                this.virtualIndex=index;

                if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
                    this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                    return null;
                }
                return this.items[index];
            },

            // Required.
            getLength: function () {
                if (this.virtualIndex > this.numLoaded_) {
                    return this.numLoaded_ ;
                }else{
                    return this.numLoaded_ + 5 ;
                }
            },

            fetchMoreItems_ : function (index) {
                if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                    self.loading = true;
                    this.toLoad_ += 20;
                    self.siAsset.getAssets(this.pageNum++,20)
                        .then(angular.bind(this, function (assets) {
                            //this.objLength = assets.length;
                            if(! assets.statusCode){
                                this.items = this.items.concat(assets);
                                this.toLoad_ = this.items.length;
                                this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                            }
                            self.loading = false;
                        }))
                }
            }
        };
        console.log('++++++++++',self.infiniteAssets)
```

```html
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" ng-show="$ctrl.infiniteAssets.getLength() > 0 && $ctrl.switch">
        
          <md-list>
            <md-list-item  class="list-page" md-on-demand md-virtual-repeat="asset in $ctrl.infiniteAssets | filter: {disabled: true } track by asset.id" ng-click="$ctrl.loadDetail(asset)">
              <span class="search-status" style="border-left-color:{{asset.statusColor}};"></span>
              <p >{{asset.name}} </p>                  
              <label hide-xs ng-if="asset.disabled" class="ng-animate-disabled">
                <md-chips >
                  <md-chip >{{'LABELS.DISABLED' | translate}}</md-chip>
                </md-chips>
              </label>
              <label ><i>{{asset.status || 'UNKNOWN'}}</i></label>
                 <md-button  aria-label="Delete Asset" class="md-icon-button md-warn" layout-padding ng-click="$ctrl.deleteAsset(asset)">
                       <md-icon md-svg-icon="delete" class="modelTrashIcon"></md-icon>
                  </md-button> 
              <md-divider></md-divider>
            </md-list-item>
          </md-list>
        </md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Comment: could you insert a plunker instead of code snippet it would be really helpful to work on the problem

Comment: track by value_to_be_trackedby  should be unique for each item in list like $index or id etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain `md-virtual-repeat` works with filters? AngularJS Materials virtual repeat is a custom implementation of ng-repeat, so you can't expect it to work exactly as the original. Here's from the documentation.

> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for ng-repeat that renders only
>   enough DOM nodes to fill the container and recycling them as the user
>   scrolls.
>
> Arrays, but not objects are supported for iteration. **Track by, as
>   alias, and (key, value) syntax are not supported**.

I would move the filtering inside your controller instead and just make sure the filter is reapplied whenever the collection changes.

Comment: i know filter in general works, i used it as a search filter before. U might be right about filter by property and objects are not supported etc

Comment: i tried using it on the controller, am i writing the code correctly ? ` self.test = self.infiniteAssets.filter(i=>i.disabled == true);
or use angular filter

self.test = self.$filter('filter')(infiniteAssets,{disabled:true}) ` and in ng repeat asset in ctrl.test

Comment: For such a simple filter there's no benefit in using angular's $filter service, so I like your first approach best. It looks correct (assuming your target browsers supports arrow functions). You just have to be certain you reapply the filter whenever your collection changes.

Comment: I am unable to use filtering with virtualRepeat. How'd you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

As per you said, `"Angular 1.5 filter with ng-repeat not working by track by id"`

I have created sample example using `AngularJs 1.5`, and used filter with track by on `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular.module('controllerAsExample', [])
  .controller('SettingsController1', SettingsController1);

function SettingsController1() {
  
   this.infiniteAssets = [
     {disabled :false, name:'test0',id:234 },
     {disabled :true, name:'test1',id:123 },
     {disabled :false, name:'test2',id:345 }
     ];
        //console.log(this.infiniteAssets);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body ng-app="controllerAsExample">

<div  ng-controller="SettingsController1 as settings">
  <p>ng-repeat with track by field example using angularjs 1.5.0:</p>
  <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="asset in settings.infiniteAssets | filter: {disabled: false } track by asset.id">
 {{asset.name}}
 </li>
 </ul>
</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well the problem is not the version. maybe the virtual repeater.  i tried using it on the controller, am i writing the code correctly ? ` self.test = self.infiniteAssets.filter(i=>i.disabled == true); or use angular filter self.test = self.$filter('filter')(infiniteAssets,{disabled:true}) ` and in ng repeat asset in ctrl.test