# AngularJS - Data Model Doesn't Bind in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="paramType" ng-change="setParamC($index)" ng-model="row.ParameterT" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamTList" required></select>

<select class="form-control" name="paramCat" ng-change="validatePCat($index)" ng-model="row.ParameterC" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamCList|filter:{ReferenceParentCode:row.ParameterT.ReferenceCode , ReferenceParentDomain:row.ParameterT.ReferenceDomain}" required></select>

<select class="form-control" name="paramName" ng-change="setParamV($index,0)" ng-model="row.ParameterN" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamNList|filter:{ReferenceParentCode:row.ParameterC.ReferenceCode , ReferenceParentDomain:row.ParameterC.ReferenceDomain}" required></select>
```

I have a list of data objects that are returned from the server to the front end via an ajax call.  Each object contains three properties (`ParameterT`, `ParameterC` and `ParameterN`) that point to other objects.

I also have three lists of objects that are used as the options for my three dropdowns.  These three lists are generated by the server and sent to the front end via the same ajax call.

The 3 lists of objects for my dropdown options and the three properties in my main data object are all the same object type.

Here's the data in my first list, `ParamTList`, as seen on the front end:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
    $$hashKey:"object:503"
    ReferenceCode:1
    ReferenceDomain:"AGG_TIER_PARAMETER_TYPE"
    ReferenceParentCode:null
    ReferenceParentDomain:null
    ReferenceValue:"Static"
    __proto__:Object
1:
    $$hashKey:"object:504"
    ReferenceCode:2
    ReferenceDomain:"AGG_TIER_PARAMETER_TYPE"
    ReferenceParentCode:null
    ReferenceParentDomain:null
    ReferenceValue:"Dynamic"
    __proto__:Object
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

and here's the `ParameterT` object:

```
{ReferenceDomain: "AGG_TIER_PARAMETER_TYPE", ReferenceCode: 2, ReferenceValue: "Dynamic", ReferenceParentDomain: null, ReferenceParentCode: null}
    ReferenceCode:2
    ReferenceDomain:"AGG_TIER_PARAMETER_TYPE"
    ReferenceParentCode:null
    ReferenceParentDomain:null
    ReferenceValue:"Dynamic"
    __proto__:Object
```

The `ParameterT` object that is used as the `ng-model` is identical to one object used in the `ng-options` list, except for the `$$hashKey` property.  I'm guessing that is why the binding does not take place.  The `ParameterT` object is a child object, but it's parent object, the main data object, does have a `$$hashKey` property.

Is that correct?
If YES, how do I get around this?
If NO, what am I doing wrong?

I could do all of this with strings istead of objects, but I'd loose the ability to filter the dropdown selections based on the previous dropdown's setting.

This currently works in production, because the three child properties are set up on the front end, by looping through all of the data objects, and then looping through the three lists of options searching for matches.  This performs poorly, that's why I'm trying to move inefficient stuff like that to the server.

Comment: In angularJS in options if you want default selection to be there you have to pass the exact same object in ng-model as in options so for this you have to do something like this $scope.row.ParameterT = $scope.pagemodel.ParamTList[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You need to use a `track by` expression in each of your `ng-options`, which is standard practice.

The reason is that if you don't, Angular creates a `$$hashkey` property on your repeated data for DOM change tracking.  And this `$$hashkey` causes the select object to be unmatchable with your http data, which doesn't have the property.

Using `track by`, Angular just compares the specified property for equality instead of the whole object (and `$$hashkey` is not added anyway.)

**Solution:**

So, using your `ParamT` as an example, and assuming there is a unique property (such as `ReferenceCode`) on each object, it would look like:

```
ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamTList track by item.ReferenceCode"
```

Otherwise you can try:

```
ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamTList track by $index"
```

which tracks by the position in the collection.

Here is a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/h4n9kdLx/);

Comment: Thanks.. I can try this when I get to the office today,  I assumed the `$$hashkey` property was added during the deserialization process after the ajax call.

Comment: Understandable but no. You could test that by logging data from an http call and seeing there is no `$$hashkey` property. It is added explicitly to the repeated model in the case of `ng-options` and `ng-repeat` so Angular knows how to update the DOM properly when data changes.  But this `$$hashkey` causes your problem because now your data object won't match the `select` objects.  If you use track by, Angular just compares the specified track by property for equality instead of the whole object (and `$$hashkey` is not added.)  Here's a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/h4n9kdLx/).

Comment: I'm getting close...  the `track by $index` does fix my initial binding problem, but now my cascading filter doesn't work.  (as shown in my drowpdown examples, setting the first dropdown limits the selections of the second...  and setting the second dropdown limits the selections of the third)  I should be able to have a `filter` and a `track by` in the same `ng-options` clause.  Correct ?

Comment: Yes. Check this for filter syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21416725/2185093 You should probably ask a new question for the dropdowns. Feel free to accept this answer for now.